# Aspose Words access Radio Button GroupName

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I am attempting to read the values filled out by a user in a Word document set up with ActiveX-based radio buttons:

[image]

When I access the ActiveX controls via `Shapes`, I do not see how I can determine `GroupName` property (highlighted above).  To be clear, I do see each of the `OptionButton` controls, including `Name`, `Caption` and `Value` properties.

```cs
var controls = document.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Shape, true)
  .Select(node => (Shape)node)
  .Where(shape => shape.OleFormat?.OleControl?.IsForms2OleControl ?? false)
  .Select(shape => (Forms2OleControl)shape.OleFormat.OleControl;

foreach (var control in controls)
{
  switch (control.Type) 
  {
    case Forms2OleControl.OptionButton:
      var caption = control.Caption;
      var selected = control.Value;
      // how can I access the `GroupName`
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current version of Aspose.Words there is no way to access group name of OLE control. The feature request has been logged as **WORDSNET-25165**.

Comment: @AlexeyNoskov could you add the Name property to that feature request? When I access either the Shape.Name or the OleFormat.OleControl.Name, it is the empty string.  By name, I am referring to the `(Name)` property in the image above. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, I have added `Name` property to the feature request.